# Badge alignment in the Communities block in the profile page

Tags: bug, design, badges, profile-page

In the Communities block in the profile page I see a small difference for vertical alignment for badges:

> [image: communities]

Following pictures is showed zoomed for better bug observing:

> [image: meta]

> [image: so]